# Does $\mathbf{T} \vdash \phi \; \iff \; \mathbf{M} \models \phi$ equivalence hold?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I re-read through my textbook section about the *completeness theorem*, and it states:

> For a countable signature $\mathcal{L}$, and a consistent set of sentences (closed-formulae) $\mathbf{T}$, there exists a model for said consistent set of sentences. It is also true that if $\lnot(\mathcal{T} \vdash \phi)$ (for some $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\phi$) then $\mathbf{T} + \lnot \phi$ has a model.

Now, my question is, that for some consistent theory, shouldn't
$$\mathbf{T} \vdash \phi \; \iff \; \mathbf{M} \models \phi$$
For $\mathbf{M} \models \mathbf{T}$ hold? I tried to take the contrapositive for $\mathbf{M} \models \phi \; \to \; \mathbf{T} \vdash \phi$, and say that $\lnot (\mathbf{T} \vdash \phi) \to \lnot (\mathbf{M} \models \phi)$ to disprove myself but it still leaves me with the gap of "why should there be no model?" or is that we can't know (thus that statement isn't always true for consistent theories, the equivalence that is)? Or am I just not asking the right question here, or does that en fact disprove it?
*Not to be confused with: "every theory is consistent if it has a model" (which is a consequence of completeness theorem [or a re-formulation of the theorem])*.

**Tl;dr** Does the soundness theorem go both ways?

Comment: This depends on the quantifier for $M$. Do you mean for all $M$? Or for some $M$? In case of the former the equivalence holds, in case of the latter it doesn't.

Comment: @MarkKamsma My intuition says the former (although, I don't know for a fact). Can you explain why regardless or put it as answer to help other people too when they skim through the internet?

Comment: Suppose $\mathbf T$ is the usual axioms for groups, $\mathbf M$ is the group $(\mathbb R,{+})$, and $\phi$ is the formula $(\forall x)(\forall y)\,xy=yx$. What is then the truth value of $\mathbf T\vdash\phi$? And of $\mathbf M\vDash \phi$? Are these truth values equal?

Comment: @Troposphere If it is true that $\mathbf{T} \vdash \phi$ (as is here trivially), since $\lnot (\mathbf{M} \models \phi) \; \land \; \mathbf{M} \models \mathbf{T} \; \to \; \mathbf{T} \vdash \phi$, then by the contrapositive $\mathbf{T} \vdash \phi \; \to \;  (\mathbf{M} \models \phi) \; \lor \; \lnot(\mathbf{M} \models \mathbf{T})$, but by the soundness theorem the LHS of the *OR* operator is true , and therefore it doesn't necessarily mean that $\mathbf{M} \models \mathbf{T}$?

Comment: @Math3147: Why do you say that the group axioms ("trivially", even) allow one to prove that the group operation is commutative? Can you show such a proof? I know many non-abelian groups, so if $\mathbf T\vdash \phi$, then we have discovered that our proof system is not _sound_.

Comment: @Troposphere I assumed that you were writing $\forall x \; \forall y \; \forall z \; (x \circ (y \circ z) = z \circ (y \circ x))$ but you just wrote it informally. I didn't understand that to be automatically abelian or non-abelian (i.e. I didn't interpret that you be multiplication as I never see commutativity stated without an operation and just assumed that was the law of composition).

Comment: @Math3147: If you want an explicit symbol the for the group operation, then my formula is $\forall x\,\forall y\;(x\circ y=y\circ x)$ -- that is, a claim that every two elements commute.

Comment: @Troposphere After I've read the answer, I think that the statement would be true for any consistent & sound theory? That is to say, the equivalence holds for theories that are consistent and sound; when only consistent, $\mathbf{T} \models \phi$, for some formula $\phi$ only?

Comment: @Math3147: There's no such thing as a "sound theory". The concept of "sound" applies to a _proof system_ (in relation to a semantics for the same language), not to an individual theory.

Comment: @Troposphere So, what should be said instead of "sound theory"? The equivalence is true for any sound formal system in which every theory is consistent?

Comment: @Math3147: The equivalence holds if the theory is _complete_. (This terminology is a bit confusing at first because the word "complete" is used about either theories or proof systems, with different technical meanings. Its duals (in some appropriately vague sense) are called "sound" for proof systems and "consistent" for theories).

Comment: @Troposphere Now, I get this "ah" moment. I totally forgot that *completeness* as a property exists. Now this "equivalence" feels a bit trivial... sorry for wasting your time. I understand intuitively now why this makes sense instead of formally only.

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark Kamsma's comment is the crux of the issue here – there are two ways of interpreting your question:

1. Is it the case that $\mathbf{T}\vdash\phi$ if and only if $\mathbf{M}\models\phi$ for every model $\mathbf{M}\models\mathbf{T}$?
2. Is it the case that $\mathbf{T}\vdash\phi$ if and only if $\mathbf{M}\models\phi$ for some model $\mathbf{M}\models\mathbf{T}$?

Note that the "only if" direction follows for both statements by the soundness theorem. So the question is really which of the "if" implications, if either, holds. The answer is that the "if" implication in Question 1 does hold, and that the "if" implication in Question 2 does not hold.

Why does it hold in the first case? Well, your idea of showing it by contrapositive is a good one; suppose that $\neg(\mathbf{T}\vdash\phi)$. The negation of the statement "$\mathbf{M}\models\phi$ for every $\mathbf{M}\models\mathbf{T}$" is the statement "$\neg(\mathbf{M}\models\phi)$ for *some* model $\mathbf{M}\models\mathbf{T}$", so to get the desired result we need only find a single model of $\mathbf{T}$ that does not model $\phi$. We can do this using the paragraph you quote from your textbook, which tells us there exists a model $\mathbf{M}$ of the theory $\mathbf{T}+\neg\phi$. Then $\mathbf{M}\models\neg\phi$, which is the same thing as $\neg(\mathbf{M}\models\phi)$. (Why?) Since also $\mathbf{M}\models\mathbf{T}$, this gives us a model of $\mathbf{T}$ that does not model $\phi$, precisely as desired.

Why does it fail to hold in the second case? Well, there are many examples of this; the simplest is arguably to take $\mathcal{L}$ to be the "empty language" and $\mathbf{T}$ to be the "empty theory", ie to take $\mathcal{L}=\varnothing$ and $\mathbf{T}=\varnothing$. Then *any* set, with no additional structure at all, is a model of $\mathbf{T}$! Now suppose that $\phi$ is the sentence $\exists x\forall y(x=y)$; can you find a model $\mathbf{M}\models T$, ie a set $\mathbf{M}$, such that $\mathbf{M}\models\phi$? If the implication in Question 2 held, then this would mean that $\mathbf{T}\vdash \phi$, and by the soundness theorem this would mean that $\mathbf{N}\models\phi$ for every model $\mathbf{N}\models \mathbf{T}$. But recall that a model of $\mathbf{T}$ is just a pure set, so for instance the structure $\mathbf{N}=\{\star,\bullet\}$ is a model of $\mathbf{T}$; can you see why $\neg(\mathbf{N}\models \phi$)? So this cannot be the case, and this gives the desired counterexample to the "if" implication in Question 2.

If that example feels too vacuous or abstract, a more "natural" example can be found in Troposphere's comment below your question. But the main takeaway is that the statement is Question 1 is correct, and the statement is Question 2 is false.

---

A few additional remarks:

1. As ℋolo comments below, one normally abbreviates the statement "$\mathbf{M}\models\phi$ for every model $\mathbf{M}\models\mathbf{T}$" by merely writing $\mathbf{T}\models\phi$. So the statement in Question 1 above can be rewritten as the pleasing symmetry that $\mathbf{T}\vdash\phi$ if and only if $\mathbf{T}\models\phi$!
2. As Troposphere comments below, the formulation by ℋolo is actually much more natural than the usual slogan for the completeness theorem, which is that "every consistent theory has a model". One can argue that consistency is actually of secondary interest to satisfiability, and that what we *really* care about in logic is the *models* of the theory, rather than one or another proof system associated to it. (See Joel David Hamkins' answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68788/completeness-vs-compactness-in-logic/68829) for an argument along those lines.) So, as Troposphere points out, from that point of view the significance of the completeness theorem is that it says our syntatic system is "strong enough" to successfully capture the meaning of truth in our semantic system (which is perhaps the thing we really care about), rather than saying that our semantic system is "weak enough" to sucessfully capture the meaning of truth in our syntatic system. See Troposphere's second comment below for a very nice example where the equivalence of these two ideas fails.
3. As Alex comments below, there is indeed a third way of framing your question, which is whether, for a fixed $\mathbf{T}$, $\mathbf{M}\models\mathbf{T}$, and $\phi$, we have that $\mathbf{T}\vdash\phi$ if and only if $\mathbf{M}\models \phi$. You can find counterexamples to this exactly as you can find counterexamples to the statement in Question 2 above; either consider the case $\mathbf{T}=\mathcal{L}=\varnothing$ as I do, or consider Troposphere's example in the comments to your question. Of course, it will certainly be possible to find examples of $\mathbf{T}$ and $\mathbf{M}$ such that $\neg(\mathbf{T}\vdash\phi)$ *and* $\neg(\mathbf{M}\models \phi)$ too! (In fact, that is precisely the content of the statement in Question 1 above.) But the point is that this will not happen in general. However, this framing of the question poses something different to think about; if there does exist a model $\mathbf{M}\models\mathbf{T}$ such that $\mathbf{M}\models\phi$ implies $\mathbf{T}\vdash\phi$ for *every* $\phi$, then what can we say about $\mathbf{T}$? In turns out that, if a model of $\mathbf{T}$ exists with that property, then actually *every* model of $\mathbf{T}$ will have that property; see if you can prove this as an exercise using the soundness theorem. In this case we say that $\mathbf{T}$ is a *[complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_theory)* theory; complete theories are of great interest in much of modern model theory.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that "$\mathbf{M}\models\phi$ for every model $\mathbf{M}\models\mathbf{T}$" is usually denoted as $\mathbf{T}⊨φ$ (and is called "semantic entailment"), so we get the nice sounding formulation of soundness: $$\mathbf{T}⊢φ⇒\mathbf{T}⊨φ\text{ (syntactic entailment implies semantics entailment)}$$And a nice formulation of completeness:$$\mathbf{T}⊨φ⇒\mathbf{T}⊢φ\text{ (semantics entailment implies syntactic entailment)}$$

Comment: @ℋolo true, a very good point! have edited :)

Comment: In fact, the above comment is how the word "completeness" makes sense in the first place -- it says that the proof system is powerful enough to prove all the true semantic entailments. Phrasing completeness as "every consistent theory has a model" is convenient for proving it, but it is not completely trivial that this is equivalent to "$\vDash$ implies $\vdash$".

Comment: I thinks there's yet a third way of reading the OP's ambiguous statement: Fix $T$, $M\models T$, and $\varphi$. Then $T\vdash \varphi$ iff $M\models \varphi$.

Comment: In fact, unless we already have soundness, the equivalence between "every consistent theory has a model" and "$\vDash$ implies $\vdash$" breaks down. Namely, take the standard $\vDash$ for first-order logic, but an (unsound) "proof system" $\vdash_0$ that proves every formula that has the constant letter $c$ in it somewhere, but nothing else. Every theory is inconsistent under $\vdash_0$ (since it proves $c=c$ as well as $\neg(c=c)$), so "every $\vdash_0$-consistent theory has a model" holds vacuously. However, we always have $T\vDash\forall x(x=x)$ yet not $T\vdash_0\forall x(x=x)$.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment. What we need for the equivalence to hold is not _soundness_ but the validity of _indirect proof_, in the shape: "if $T+\neg\varphi$ is inconsistent, then $T\vdash\varphi$". The $\vdash_0$ above lacks this property too. To see that the culprit was not lack of _soundness_, consider _propositional_ calculus with classical semantics but intuitionistic proofs. The proof system is clearly _sound_, and thanks to the double-negation translation every consistent theory is satisfiable -- but the proof system is not _complete_.